# elasticsearch-py and multiprocessing

Tags: python, pyelasticsearch

What is the correct way to use elasticsearch-py in multiprocessing script? Should I create a new client object before start processes and use that object or should I create a new object inside each of the processes. The 2nd one gives me an an error with connection issues from elasticsearch

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: The second one should work (works for me). Could you show traceback / code sample?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the first method works for me, when I declare the client object as a global variable.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import time


def task(body):
    result = es.index(index='test', doc_type='test', body=body)
    return result


def main():
    pool = Pool(processes=MAX_CONNECTS)
    result = []
    for x in range(10):
        result.append(pool.apply_async(task, ({'id': x},)))
    time.sleep(1)
    for rs in result:
        print(rs.get())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MAX_CONNECTS = 5
    es = Elasticsearch(hosts="localhost", maxsize=MAX_CONNECTS)
    main()
```

The output looks like

```
{'_index': 'test', '_type': 'test', '_id': 'xEjqBWcB9xsUYKqz-P6U', '_version': 1, 'result': 'created', '_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 1, 'failed': 0}, '_seq_no': 1, '_primary_term': 1}
{'_index': 'test', '_type': 'test', '_id': 'w0jqBWcB9xsUYKqz-P6U', '_version': 1, 'result': 'created', '_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 1, 'failed': 0}, '_seq_no': 0, '_primary_term': 1}
{'_index': 'test', '_type': 'test', '_id': 'x0jqBWcB9xsUYKqz-P6X', '_version': 1, 'result': 'created', '_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 1, 'failed': 0}, '_seq_no': 4, '_primary_term': 1}
{'_index': 'test', '_type': 'test', '_id': 'xkjqBWcB9xsUYKqz-P6X', '_version': 1, 'result': 'created', '_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 1, 'failed': 0}, '_seq_no': 3, '_primary_term': 1}
{'_index': 'test', '_type': 'test', '_id': 'xUjqBWcB9xsUYKqz-P6W', '_version': 1, 'result': 'created', '_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 1, 'failed': 0}, '_seq_no': 2, '_primary_term': 1}
{'_index': 'test', '_type': 'test', '_id': 'yEjqBWcB9xsUYKqz-P66', '_version': 1, 'result': 'created', '_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 1, 'failed': 0}, '_seq_no': 4, '_primary_term': 1}
{'_index': 'test', '_type': 'test', '_id': 'ykjqBWcB9xsUYKqz-P7I', '_version': 1, 'result': 'created', '_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 1, 'failed': 0}, '_seq_no': 2, '_primary_term': 1}
{'_index': 'test', '_type': 'test', '_id': 'yUjqBWcB9xsUYKqz-P7I', '_version': 1, 'result': 'created', '_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 1, 'failed': 0}, '_seq_no': 3, '_primary_term': 1}
{'_index': 'test', '_type': 'test', '_id': 'y0jqBWcB9xsUYKqz-P7P', '_version': 1, 'result': 'created', '_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 1, 'failed': 0}, '_seq_no': 4, '_primary_term': 1}
{'_index': 'test', '_type': 'test', '_id': 'zEjqBWcB9xsUYKqz-P7V', '_version': 1, 'result': 'created', '_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 1, 'failed': 0}, '_seq_no': 5, '_primary_term': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to create a unique client object and you can increase the number of simultaneous thread using the `maxsize` (10 by default).

`es = Elasticsearch( "host1", maxsize=25)`

[Source](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html#thread-safety)

Comment: Wrong: In the link you have posted above "Since we use persistent connections throughout the client it **means that the client doesn’t tolerate fork very well**. If your application calls for multiple processes make sure you create a fresh client after call to fork. Note that Python’s multiprocessing module uses fork to create new processes on POSIX systems."